# How to Fix AttributeError: module 'magpylib" has no attribute 'source'

Tags: python, magpylib

I have tried installing the magpylib module onto both VSCode and Anaconda(Spyder) and have received identical errors. I am relatively new to programming and do not know how to fix it, neither have I found a similar question. For the code I used the first example code given by the [site](https://magpylib.readthedocs.io/en/gettingstartedreview/_pages/x_examples/).

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import magpylib as magpy

# create magnets
magnet1 = magpy.source.magnet.Box(mag=[0,0,600],dim=[3,3,3],pos=[-4,0,3])
magnet2 = magpy.source.magnet.Cylinder(mag=[0,0,500], dim=[3,5], pos=[0,0,0])

# manipulate magnets
magnet1.rotate(45,[0,1,0],anchor=[0,0,0])
magnet2.move([5,0,-4])

# collect magnets
pmc = magpy.Collection(magnet1,magnet2)

# display system geometry
pmc.displaySystem()

# calculate B-fields on a grid
xs = np.linspace(-10,10,20)
zs = np.linspace(-10,10,20)
Bs = np.array([[pmc.getB([x,0,z]) for x in xs] for z in zs])

# display fields using matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs,zs)
U,V = Bs[:,:,0], Bs[:,:,2]
ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=np.log(U**2+V**2), density=1.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```py
import magpylib as magpy

magnet1 = magpy.magnet.Box(magnetization=[0, 0, 600], dimension=[3, 3, 3], position=[-4, 0, 3])
```

You might have found a deprecated example.

For your future questions, please provide a minimal code, i.e. a code reproducing the error in a minimum of lines AND you python version. In your case :

```
import magpylib as magpy

magnet1 = magpy.source.magnet.Box(mag=[0, 0, 600], dim=[3, 3, 3], pos=[-4, 0, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

try to install an old version of magpylib
for exemple :

```
pip install magpylib==2.3.0b0
```